# Can you feel the beat, Les?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image: Jumble of lines]

---

Hint:

> The band’s name is hidden in the title of this puzzle.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker I tagged this question [enigmatic-puzzle].  The official description for this tag is, “Puzzles where the genre or solving strategy of the puzzle is not explicitly stated; puzzles where the puzzler must deduce what type of puzzle it is.”

Comment: I didn’t downvote (I upvoted) but I would guess that downvotes could be because of the arbitrary (it’s not like users with high rep have some sort of advantage over new users that needs to be overcome) and unsportsmanlike stipulation as to who may answer

Comment: @caPNCApn First of all, thanks for the upvote.  By encouraging people with 200 or more reputation points to temporarily hold off on answering, what I am really trying to do is be friendly and welcoming to newcomers.

Comment: @caPNCApn I’m a sportsman, and you don’t speak for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> All You Need Is Love

because...

> You can add lines that line up with the given fragments which spell out this phrase, which is also a [song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Need_Is_Love) by The Beatles! (This is relevant because the title is "Can you feel **the beat, Les**?")
>  [image: the answer]